# Sylow p-subgroups, normal subgroups and the center subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Let:
$G$ be a finite group.
$p$ be a prime number.
$P$ be a Sylow-p subgroup of $G$.
If $p\mid o(G)$ and for every $(a,b)\in G$, $(ab)^p=a^pb^p$, please help me prove the following:
(1) $P\triangleleft G$.
(2) There is $N\triangleleft G$ so that $PN=G$ and $P\cap N=1$.
(3) $Z(G)\ne 1$ when $Z(G)$ is the center of $G$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the solution;

Let $f_k$ be function from $G$ to $G$ with $f_k(x)=x^{(p^k)}$ where k is an positive integer then $f_k$ is homomorphism since $(ab)^p$=$a^p b^p$ $\implies$ $(ab)^{p^k}$=$a^{p^k} b^{p^k}$.

Now let $P\in Syl_P(G)$ and $|P|=p^n$ then as we said $f_n$ is an homomorphism and you can easily see that $Ker(f_n)$ is set of all elements in $G$ having order which is equal to a power of $p$.So,$Ker(f_n)$ is a p group containing $P$,by maximality of $P$, $P=Ker(f_n)$.

$Im(f_n)$ is also a subgroup of $G$ and has no element having an oreder which is a power of $p$.Thus, $Ker(f_n)\cap Im(f_n)=${$1$}.Let $x\in Im(f_n)$ then $x=g^r$ for some $g$ in $G$ where $r=p^n$ then $h^{-1}xh=h^{-1}g^rh=(h^{-1}gh)^r$ thus $h^{-1}xh\in Im(f_n)$ $\implies$ $Im(f_n)$ is normal in $G$ .

Then $G\cong PxN$,Where $P=Ker(f_n)$ and $N=Im(f_n)$ $\implies$ $Z(G)\cong Z(P)xZ(N)$ since $Z(P)$ is nontrivial as it is center of the p-group then $Z(G)$ is nontrivial.

Comment: Thank you :) 
Can you please explain why $h^{-1}g^rh=(h^{-1}gh)^r$?

Comment: you are welcome, for example   $(h^{-1}gh)^2=h^{-1}ghh^{-1}gh=h^{-1}g^2h$ for r same procedure.